# Disable didSelectRowAtIndex --- tap -> hold touch -> begin edit -> end edit -> release touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have seen posts where it is suggested to return nil in `willSelectRowAtIndexPath`, if `didSelectRowAtIndex` is to be disabled while editing `UITableViewCell`.
But my question goes around the tapping the cell first, and then without releasing the touch, begin and end the edit using swipe.
Ideally, `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` will block `didSelectRowAtIndex` once the cell is in editing mode. But in this case, `didSelectRowAtIndex` is first fired and **without releasing the touch**, cell begins and end editing without any action.
In this case, on ending the edit (after `didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath`), `didSelectRowAtIndex` gets fired. How can I avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

I created custom cell and added some logic to see whether cell was editing previously before selecting it, it worked for me!

Here is code:
Table View Methods-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    if cell.cellWasEditing() { 
        //this is main logic
        return nil
    }
    return indexPath
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}
```

Custom Cell-

```
@IBOutlet weak var _customLbl: UILabel!

private var prevEditingState = UITableViewCellStateMask.DefaultMask
private var wasEdititng = false

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

override func didTransitionToState(state: UITableViewCellStateMask) {

    if prevEditingState == UITableViewCellStateMask.ShowingEditControlMask || prevEditingState == UITableViewCellStateMask.ShowingDeleteConfirmationMask {
        wasEdititng = true
    }
    else {
        wasEdititng = false
    }
    prevEditingState = state
}

//MARK: Public Methods
func setCellIndexLabel(index: Int) {
    _customLbl!.text = String(index)
}

func cellWasEditing() -> Bool {
    if wasEdititng {
        wasEdititng = false
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem!!

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use custom cell, and add a UIPanGestureRecognizer on it.

Then monitor the gesture state, and do what you want when the state is end.